# Install Windows 8 app (appx) remotely via PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-8, appx

As the title says.
My scenario is I have some company app that want to install to all of machines in network.
I know that I can install .exe and .msi remotely from my machine to any machines in network via PowerShell. Can I do the same thing with Windows 8 app (appx)? If there's anyway how?
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [sideloading and requires some work](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/jj874388.aspx) like signing the App and installing the certificate. You can [use the System Center 2012 Configuration Manager SP1 to automate this](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj822984.aspx).

Comment: I can sideload the app if I can physically access to the machine. But I need some method to do it remotely. 
Example: If I want to force some machine in other city that have company app installed to update the app, how can I do that?

Comment: Don't bother my last comment. I just found out! Just add the command for sideload app inside Invoke-Command scriptblock! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, using Windows Powershell Invoke-Command should get you where you need. However, you will need to find a way to get the Appx package file to the remote machine (you've obviously done this before with the MSI files), and you will need to ensure the Windows App Store developer certificate is valid on the remote machine as well.